# How can I get sum of width ,padding , border and margin in pixel?

Tags: javascript, css

I want get width of element included element itself width, border(if has), padding and margin(Not JQuery)?

Comment: Is `margin` part of the element's size...curious to know. What about collapsing margins?

Comment: I want get all area size that an element take it.

Comment: You want to get it for a code or you just wanna know? If you use **box-sizing:border-box**, you can get the whole width without the margin. You can see all of them by inspecting the element...

Comment: @Paulie_D: No, it's not part of the element's size. The margin is the minimum distance to surrounding elements or non-collapsing boundaries. A bottom margin of one element is not added to the top margin of the element below, the larger margin determines the distance between them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [**Element.getBoundingClientRect()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) for the width without margins, and **[Window.getComputedStyle()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)** for the margins:

```js
var d= document.querySelector('div'),
    cs= getComputedStyle(d);

console.log(d.getBoundingClientRect().width +
            parseFloat(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-left')) +
            parseFloat(cs.getPropertyValue('margin-right'))
           );
```

```css
div {
  width: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 5px solid green;
  margin-left: 15px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  This is a test
</div>
```

Even though the CSS above uses whole numbers only, the result may have decimals.  In Chrome, a border style of `5px` results in an actual border of `4.54545450210571px`.